# gradle plugin custom task out of memory

Tags: gradle, out-of-memory, build.gradle, heap-memory

I developed one utility in maven and i am using that utilities fat jar in my custom gradle plugin.gradle plugin is developed in java when I am using this plugin in gradle project.This plugin is working fine but for some cases whenever I tries to run gradle task  I am getting following error :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space caused by :java.lang.outOfMemoryError : Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458)
at org.apache.pig.data.DefaultAbstractBag.add(DefaultAbstractBag.java:116)
```

I think this error is due to java heap space, gradle task is running out of heap space, could you please let me know  how should I increase heap size for gradle java task so as to solve this issue.

My sample gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
buildscript{
   repositories{
      mavenCentral()
      mavenLocal()
   }
   dependencies{
      classpath 'com.abc.pqrPlugin:pqrPlugin:1.3.2'
   }
}

apply plugin:'pqr-plugin'

task pqrTask(type: com.abc.pqrPlugin.PqrTask) {}
```

Total RAM my system is having is 8GB and I tried setting java heap size up to 6GB and permgen up to 2GB but no luck.

Comment: can you share the sources of your plugin?

Comment: i cant share source code of plugin due to my organisation restrictions but i as I said in problem statement at backend we are using java based fat jar utility that uses org.apache.pig version 0.14 to execute pig scripts we are sending pig scripts to utility through plugin

Comment: Maybe add `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/heapdumps` to GRADLE_OPTS and use those to figure out what's taking so much memory. Also `jvisualvm` while you're running the build.

Comment: @EricWendelin : my concern is not to find out who is taking so much memory my concern is how to increase the memory of gradle java task so that gradle task will not  throw  heap memory out of space error I tried increasing memory of gradle task but i think gradle is unable to apply the memory space that I am mentionining

Comment: guys any update over this please?